# How to do this probability question involving independent events?

Tags: probability

```
Quark hunting is a dangerous occupation. 
On a quark hunt, there is a probability of  1/ 4  
that the hunter is killed. 
The quark is twice as likely to be killed as the hunter. 
There is a probability of  1/ 3  that both survive. 
Find probability that 
(ii)  both the hunter and the quark die
(iii) the hunter lives and the quark dies 
(iv)  the hunter lives, given that the quark dies.
```

(I) isnt it P(hunter dies)* P(quark dies)= 1/4*(1/4*2)=1/8

But this is wrong because ans is 1/12.

(ii)   P(hunter live)* P(quark dies)= (1-1/4)*(1-1/2)=3/8

But this is wrong because ans is 5/12.

(iii)P(hunter live and quark die) ÷ P(quark dies)= 3/8 ÷ 1/2 =3/4

but this is wrong too answer is 5/6.

Can someone point out the mistake please?

Comment: The model is wrong. In your model both survive with the probability of $\frac12\cdot\frac34$

Comment: Are you sure that the events are independent? For me, the statement "The quark is twice as likely to be killed as the hunter" and "there is a probability of 1/3 that both survive" are contradictory, if the events are independent. Why? Let's set
$$
P(\text{H killed}) = h = \frac{1}{4}
$$
$$
P(\text{Q killed}) = q
$$
If these are independent, then we should have
$$
P(\text{H survives and Q survives}) = (1-h)(1-q) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
which would yield $q=\frac{5}{9}$ <- Contradiction! This cannot really be interpreted as "twice as likely"...

Answer (score 1):

P(neither die)=$\frac13$

P(at least one dies)=$\frac23$

P(H dies)=$\frac14$

P(Q dies)=$\frac12$

Let P(both die)=$x$

So the probability that just the hunter dies is $\frac14-x$, and for just the quark dies is $\frac12-x$.

So P(neither die)+P(only H dies)+P(only Q dies)+P(both die)=$1$, and so

P(only H dies)+P(only Q dies)+P(both die)=$1$-P(neither die)

P(only H dies)+P(only Q dies)+P(both die)=$\frac23$

then $\frac23=\frac14-x+\frac12-x+x$, which gives $x=\frac1{12}$.

Comment: Can you explain the formula you used? @JMP

Comment: @JMP I think you flipped the probabilities of death: the hunter dies with probability $1/4$, not the quark.

Comment: In other words, 
\begin{array}{r|cc}
&\hbox{Hunter survives}&\hbox{Hunter dies}\\
\hline
\hbox{Quark survives}&\frac13&A\\
\hbox{Quark dies}&B&x
\end{array}, it's given that $p(A)+x=\frac14$, $p(B)+x=\frac12$ and ii) is $x$, iii) is $p(B)$, iv) is $p(B)/(p(B)+x)$ @JMP